# iScala ERP system department field

Tags: database, erp

Does anyone know where I can find the department field in the iScala ERP system?

Fields are broadly speaking combinations of letters and numbers so difficult to discern sense from any of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the table names GL03%C%C%Y%Y on column GL03001 check the letter corresponding to the department field in your system utilities parameter list